# entry point of the application

Tags: c#, reflection

What static method of the Assembly class should be called to guarantee that an instance of an assembly which has an entry point of the application will be returned?

Comment: The static methods are instance-less. They are supposed NOT to know of their class instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly)?